# configurar o breakpoint no eclipse Luna

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp

Ja vasculhei na net e YouTube e não encontrei uma forma de se configurar o breakpoint no eclipse Luna com PDT utilizo o windows e com servidor utilizo wamp e as em outras maquinas o XAMPP, alguem poderia me da uma luz ou indicar um tutorial que possa me ajudar desde já muito grato.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Qual extensão de debug vai usar? Xdebug? Zend? Já ativou no php.ini? Já configurou as portas? É ambiente virtualizado?

Comment: respondendo a primeira pergunta Zend Engine v2.5.0, não ativei no php.ini, nao configurei as portas, e eh ambiente local(localhost) sou iniciante

Comment: Primeiro você precisa habilitar o xdebug no php.ini, remova o `;` dessa linha ou similar `zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll` reinicie o apache. Agora configure o php no eclipse, window>preference>php>php executables